# UWP add item to Shadow receivers from xaml

Tags: xaml, uwp, shadow

How can i add rectangle to shadow receivers from xaml ? I cant use codebehind or another code , only xaml.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <ThemeShadow x:Key="SharedShdow">
            <ThemeShadow.Receivers>
                
            </ThemeShadow.Receivers>
        </ThemeShadow>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <Rectangle Fill="Turquoise" Width="100" Height="100" Shadow="{StaticResource SharedShdow}" Translation="0,0,30">
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible. This is because the `Receivers` is a get only list of which you can modify the items, but it is not possible to redefine this list.

Therefore you need to individually add controls to the `Receivers` list, which needs to be done in code-behind.